# visual studio cant connect database

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, connection-string

using sql server managment studio I can connect database using sever authentication with

```
    login = sa , password = 1
```

But I cant connect using server explorer (and from web app) in visual studio.

```
      <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=XXX.mdf;Integrated Security=False;User Id=sa;Password=1"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**login failed for user sa**

Can somebody answer this strange behavior?

I have 64bit Enterprize edition.  Thanks.

Comment: Is the database in SQL Server actually called `XXX.mdf`?  That looks like a file name.

Comment: Sorry.I forget specify error message - login failed for user sa.

Comment: "Login failed" is pretty generic.  It's good practice for a system not to provide information about the failure to an unauthenticated user.  It won't tell you things like "The username was right, but not the password" or "That account has access to another database, but not this one" or anything like that.  It's likely you'd still get "login failed" even if the database doesn't exist, and I continue to suspect that `XXX.mdf` doesn't exist.

Comment: please make as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Database=XXX.mdf
```

Is your database *actually called* `XXX.mdf`?  I suspect it isn't, since that looks like a file name, and is perhaps just called `XXX` instead.  The login will fail if the database isn't correct, since the server isn't going to give information about the failure to an unauthenticated user.  Try:

```
Database=XXX
```